# pass parameter from loop value to dynamic function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am making loop to make an array of Timers and give each timer a function

here's something like what i did:

```
dim timer(10) as Timer
for i = 0 to 5
timer(i) = new Timer
AddHandler timer(i).Tick, Function(senderX, eX) timerFunction(i)
next
```

i have this function:

```
Private Function timerFunction(ByVal timerNo As Integer)
    MsgBox(timerNo)
End Function
```

but i am getting `6` as the value of `timerNo` for every `timer` i call with this:

```
timer(3).Start()
```

i outputs `6` even in i change the parameter to a number from `1` to  `5`

why is it diong that?

Comment: `timerFunction`'s value of `timerNo` is calculated at the time the function is called, not when you do the `AddHandler`. See https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Comment: You should have got a compiler warning: "BC42324 Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable."

Answer (score 1):

You have "closed over the loop variable". The value of `timerNo` is evaluated at the time the function is called which is always after the loop has completed, so the value of `timerNo` will always be 6.

You should have got a compiler warning: "`BC42324 Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results. Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.`"

To do this with your example...

```
Dim timer(10) As Timer
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
  Dim j As Integer = i
  timer(i) = New Timer
  timer(i).Interval = 1000
  timer(i).Enabled = True
  AddHandler timer(i).Tick, Function(senderX, eX) timerFunction(j)
Next

Function timerFunction(timerNo As Integer) As String
  MsgBox(timerNo)
  Return timerNo.ToString
End Function
```

This way, a new instance of `j` is created for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I already have the solution by using 
Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(timer, CType(sender2, System.Windows.Forms.Timer))

but thank you really for this.. I'll look around it and maybe use it. Cheers!